# Design a full adder to add two 4-bits integer and measuring on 4 quantum states

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience

I am trying to implement a full adder with minimum of 8 qubits to add two 4 bit integers. Integer 1 will be added on q[0-3] while integer 2 will be added on q[4-7]. The output will be measured on q[0-3].

So far I created a full adder to be measured on 2 states but I am having trouble manipulating this code to measure on 4 states. Below is qiskit code:

```
qc = QuantumCircuit(8,2)

# AND gate1 implementation
qc.ccx(0,1,3)

# OR gate1 implementation
qc.cx(0,4) 
qc.cx(1,4)

# OR gate2 implementation
qc.cx(2,5) 
qc.cx(4,5)

# AND gate2 implementation
qc.ccx(2,4,6)

# OR gate implementation
qc.x(3)
qc.x(6)
qc.ccx(3,6,7)
qc.x(7)
```

Comment: What kind of trouble do you have with measurement? I do not see `measure` command in your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are aiming to perform arithmetic on a quantum computer, you should take a  look at methods that involve the Quantum Fourier Transform: https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.00443